# How to allow background div scrollable when modal is open

Tags: javascript, html, css

the shadow view is a modal when it pops up, I still want my background div behind the shadow view scrollable. Is there a way to achieve that?

```
.main-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
 }
```

I need to have overflow-y to be auto in order to implement react-infinite-scroller framework.

This is modal HTML and css

```
<div class="modal-backdrop"></div>
<div class="modal"
  tabindex="-1"
  role="dialog"
  (click)="onClose()"
  >
</div>
.modal {
   overflow-x: hidden;
   overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for

```js
const showDialog = () => {
  document.getElementById('dialog').classList.add('show');
  const scrollY = document.documentElement.style.getPropertyValue('--scroll-y');
  const body = document.body;
};
const closeDialog = () => {
  const body = document.body;
  const scrollY = body.style.top;
  body.style.position = '';
  body.style.top = '';
  window.scrollTo(0, parseInt(scrollY || '0') * -1);
  document.getElementById('dialog').classList.remove('show');
};
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--scroll-y', `${window.scrollY}px`);
});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#text {
  max-width: 800px;
}
#dialog {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10vh;
  left: 10vw;
  width: 80vw;
  height: 80vw;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
}
#dialog.show {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#dialog span {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
#show,
#close {
  background: #da1b60;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 200px;
}
#show:hover,
#close:hover {
  background: #ff8a00;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#show {
  position: fixed;
  top: 30px;
  left: 10px;
}
#close {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<button id='show' onClick='showDialog()'>Show Dialog</button>
<div id='text'>
...Your Content here...
</div>
<div id='dialog'>
  <span>Oh wow, modal! We can close this now.</span>
  <button id='close' onClick='closeDialog()'>Close Dialog</button>
</div>
```